# sending COOP and COEP headers in reactnode app

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, cross-origin-opener-policy, cross-origin-embedder-policy

I have a deployed app that is built on Express (Node) and uses a built React frontend for app rendering.

Currently, I'm facing SharedArrayBuffer issues and need to pass these headers to make my code work:

```
To opt in to a cross-origin isolated state, you need to send the following HTTP headers on the main document:


Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

Where and how would I go about doing this? New to full stack development haha.

Comment: What are you serving the built react app from? via express?

Comment: yes @Matt i am using express

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on a project where I also encountered the SharedArrayBuffer issue when integrating ffmpeg-wasm.

This first snippet from [cross origin resource policy issue when playing files from s3 on deployed app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68591422/16676589) solved my problem. This would go in your server.js (note that the sequence is important, set headers *before* express.static):

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
      res.header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
      next();
    });
    
    app.use(express.static(...));
```

Alternatively:

```
    const customHeaders = (res, path, stat) => {
      res.append("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
      res.append("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin"); 
    }

    app.use(express.static(...), {
      setHeaders: customHeaders
    });
```

Note that there are some issues with this approach:

- SharedArrayBuffer is not supported in Safari and some other browsers, see https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer
- All cross-origin loads from the browser will fail, for example external scripts (e.g. Analytics) or image loads from other domains

Comment: this is nice, but how do you set these headers when you dont build with static and your client isnt server-side rendered?